# Connecting PIR sensor to VB.net using Arduino

Tags: visual-studio, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to use the motion sensor (PIR) to be able to understand when there is some movement, then, from the Arduino, it will notify my application in Visual Basic.

In general, the idea is to intervene when an elderly person stays in bed for too long, if the sensor does not detect anything in 3 hours (excluding hours of sleep) it will alert the vb.net application and send an audio message over to sound speakers, like for example "Get up and walk.".

I hope you can help me, thanks for your attention.

I've done some research on the subject and haven't found anything for this specific situation.
I maked this code, just so I can test the copnnection, but its not working.
Imports System.IO.Ports 'importa a biblioteca de portas seriais

VB.net Code

```
Imports System.IO.Ports 

Public Class Form1
  Dim mySerialPort As New SerialPort("COM3") 
  Dim alarmSound As New Media.SoundPlayer("C:\alarm.wav")
  
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600 
    mySerialPort.Open() 
  End Sub
  
  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim pirState As String = mySerialPort.ReadLine() 
    If pirState = "1" Then
       alarmSound.Play()
    Else
      alarmSound.Stop()
    End If
  End Sub
  
  Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    mySerialPort.Close() 
  End Sub
End Class
```

Arduino Code

```
const int pirPin = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int pirState = digitalRead(pirPin); 
  Serial.println(pirState); 
  delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: Its very hard to say why is something not working like that. 
Instead - try to build your solution from smaller blocks, for example - the first part is to see that your arduino is working properly, use a console program like putty, mobaXterm or Arduino's IDE built-it terminal connection (ctrl+shift+m) to see what are the outputs you are getting from the arduino.